# Contract.Ensures and Exception Handling

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I recently discovered the .NET Contracts API, and, although I don't like the way of implementation using methods and not an extended syntax (*Sing#* did it right, in my opinion), I prefer using them over the old / regular way using if's for e.g. null-checking.

I'm also approaching my first Contract.Ensures-calls and I stumbled over the question how we would deal with Exceptions in a method containing a Contract.Ensures that suffered from an exception while running?

The word Contract.*Ensures* kinda feels like I have to handle the exceptions inside the method and get my class into correct state again, but what if I couldn't?

Let's say we have this class here:

```
public class PluginManager
{
    private ILoadedFromAtCompileTimeUnknownAssembly extension;

    public bool IsFinished { get; private set; }

    public void Finish()
    {
        extension.Finish();
        this.IsFinished = true;
    }
}
```

can we use Contract.Ensures to ensure IsFinished is true after the method completed?

Comment: You use contracts to *prevent* your class from getting into a wrong state.  It didn't finish since your contract said that it wasn't finished correctly.  So don't set it to *true*.  Actually recovering from this is very unlikely, don't try.  Log the exception, terminate the program, fix the bug.

Comment: @HansPassant And what is with a property that I am only able to get from a wrapper class? Such as `Contract.Ensures(Loader.Count == 0)` in e.g. `UnloadAll() { Loader.UnloadAll(); }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Ensures basically means "Ensures if the method terminates normally", i.e. without exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I find it very hard to get the concept of code contracts right. Code Contracts are meant to find programming errors. If applied that way you can remove the contracts of your release build and your application will continue to work perfectly.

BUT it is very hard to distinguish programming (aka logic errors) from configuration and input data issues. These checks must remain in your release builds. It is therefore a bad idea to use Code Contracts to check if an extension/plugin did correctly load because it is usually configured into your application. If you remove the contracts in your release build you get differerent behaviour of your application depending if you configure your app wrong in debug or release builds.

Contract violations are reported with only one exception type which makes it impossible to react in upper layers of your application to e.g. a configuration issue or a logic bug in your application. With react I do not mean to continue but to present a remotely useful message to the user/developer what went wrong.

Code Contract do look nice at the surface but I fear that most people use it in the wrong way. It is not meant to replace all of your null checks for input validation in your methods. You should replace only from the methods the null checks with code contracts where your are sure that a logic problem an not the input data is the root cause.

If you expect a file name in your e.g. console application as input and the the user did forget to supply the file name at the command line it is not a good idea to the greet the user with a ContracException.

- The error message would be confusing to the user.
- You cannot differentate programming errors from user input validation issues.
- You cannot catch any specific ContractException because the exception type is internal.

See [user documentation](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf).

> 7.6 ContractException The ContractException type is not a public type and is emitted as a nested private type into each assembly for which
>   runtime contract checking is enabled. It is thus not possible to write
>   catch handlers catching only ContractException . Contract exceptions
>   can thus only be handled as part of a general exception backstop. The
>   rationale for this design is that programs should not contain control
>   logic that depends on contract failures, just like programs should not
>   catch ArgumentNullException or similar validation exceptions.

Comment: So if the main reason I liked the contracts so much (static null-checks) isn't even made to be used in every method, I kinda worry about why they created contracts in the first place.
I really like the way they did it in Sing#, with a ! appended to a type to declare it non-nullable. Would be my #1 Feature request in C# 6.0.

Comment: To be honest I do not think Code Contracts are a good idea for general purpose code. They are useful for algorithms to catch edge cases with such additional instrumentation. But in normal "business code" it very hard to follow the data flow accross all layers to be sure that this one input validation check can be safely removed in release builds and is a good condidate for Code Contracts.

Comment: As I understand it, Code Contracts were exactly designed to prevent malicious parameters, but the way the Contracts Team was implementing them is rather cumbersome than helpful.

Comment: Extended syntax would've been much more useful, as the compiler could remove all checks for parametes that are guaranteed to be e.g. not null / fullfill the contract.

Comment: @NeoLegends I'm not sure what you mean by "malicious". Code Contracts are meant to guard against programmer error. I'd also recommend against removing all parameter checks from runtime code, as the static verifier is not perfect.

Comment: Plugins loaded at runtime could be bad for the code, and leaving those contracts in there would protect against them. But yeah, I already stopped using Contracts because it cluttered my code rather than cleaning it up.